# ctkahp quit unexpectedly

Tags: macos

I am getting "ctkahp quit unexpectedly" regularly on my macOS Sierra 10.12.1 Mac Mini.

I cannot find any resources about what this process is.

When this error occurs, my machine can't connect to the internet at all and I get a ton of errors, iCloud, etc.

I have to reboot to make it go away.

Comment: ctkahp is part of the [CryptoTokenKit](http://www.macinside.info/process.php?id=12409) framework introduced in Yosemite. How do you connect to the internet?

Comment: wifi & ethernet (both are active).

Comment: Perhaps it was a firewall issue, e.g. like Snitch or Flocker?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in an environment that uses Active Directory. When I attempted to run Chrome, I would get the error. The error mentioned the CryptoTokenKit, or something like that.

Oddly enough, other accounts on the same machine worked fine.

When I dug deeper, I found that the client did NOT have a Mobile Me account. Setting them up with a Mobile Me account appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: How did you set up a Mobile Me account in 2017?